# Develop for Facebook Page API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I was developing a web application which shows posts from specified pages. While development I used "Graph API Explorer" App to test the application as it always returned a permission error when I try to use my App. Since few days back they have removed  "Graph API Explorer" App from Graph API Explorer. I understand that we need Special approval to use Facebook pages API. But to get that approval we have to show a screencast of our application. So first we have to develop the application. But we have to test API requests while developing and there is no way to do that now.

Could someone please guide me how we should develop for facebook pages API. How we should test. Is there any specific dev permissions available.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: That error seems to disappear once the `page` field is removed. And considering that https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/search#fields doesn’t even list such a field, I wonder what you’re trying to achieve by specifying it in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe Well the above worked fine till last week. If you just try this URL even for places API. It still give the same error.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/226074437976543?method=GET&path=1887761418185182%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cpage&version=v3.0

Comment: Yeah well nothing surprising about that - places are essentially pages, and so you have to submit your app for review now if you want to access any data of public pages you have no admin access to - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: @CBroe. Thank you. But my issue is I am the admin of several pages I have, so if I have to test the app, i should get those pages information at least. Also the main issue is Facebook needs screencast of the application to show how we use facebook. So without access to API, at least a sandbox or developer one we can'd develop that to show them.

Comment: So what permissions did you grant the app? manage_pages or at least pages_show_list are necessary so that the API _knows_ that this is the admin of a page making the request.

Comment: I added page_show_list permission

Comment: so long story short, I'm curious what are the permission needed to use pages API?